# Graphically, why is $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x} dx$ divergent but $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^{0.999}} dx$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, integration

When the power of $x$ is less than 1, it seems that the improper integral converges. I understand the math, but I don't understand how the graphs of the two cases $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x^{0.999}}$ are fundamentally different.

Comment: They are different in the same way that $1/x$ and $1/x^2$ are different on $[1,\infty)$

Comment: We can let the power become arbitrarily close to 1 and have the integral converge, but the limit as the power becomes 1 is infinity, so the integral diverges.

Comment: Well, there is no such thing as graphical convergence. If you understand  the math that is the end of it. In the same line of argument you could ask why is $1^n$ constant and equal to 1 while $0.999^n$ converges to zero? If you just plot it and don't consider enough values for $n$ you could think the two situations are the same. A similar thing happens with you example.

Comment: This is a very good question! Specially that 0.99999999...99 = 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right the graphs aren't fundamental different, but the integral of $\frac{1}{x^{0.99999}}$ from $0$ to $1$ is a large number and if you take an exponent, that is closer to $1$ the number gets even larger.

For demonstration let $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Then
$$
\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x^\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^1 x^{-\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x
= \frac{1}{1-\alpha} {x^{1-\alpha}}\,\bigg\vert_0^1 = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}
$$
This shows that the integral will grow arbitrarily large, if $\alpha$ gets very close to $1$. So there is nothing contra intuitive about that.

Comment: The result should be $$1/(1-\alpha)$$ right ?

Comment: @Dicordi yes I edited it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We can integrate to see why.
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x} = \lim_{a\to0} \ln(x)\Big|_a^{1} = \lim_{a\to0} -\ln(a)$$
This value clearly diverges. However, for $x^{0.999}$, we find that
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^{0.999}} = 1000x^{0.0001}\Big|_0^{1} = 1000$$.
The reason for divergence is the special integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ compared to other 'powers'.

**Edit:** The graphs are not fundamentally different; the reason for divergences is more analytic rather thang graphical/geometric.

Comment: You don't really answer the question of the OP about graphical evidence.

Comment: @JeanMarie my bad I seemed to have missed that part.